# Send Echo Messages in PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

I have the following php code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests ORDER BY RequestID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "Name: " . $row1['FirstName'] . " " . $row1['LastName'];
echo "<br> Date Needed: " . $row1['DateNeeded'];
echo "<br> Company: " . $row1['Company'] . "<br> Account: " . $row1['Account'] . "<br> Brand: " . $row1['Brand'] . "<br> Wants: ";
    $requestID = $row1['RequestID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ItemsPerRequest, Items WHERE Items.ItemID = ItemsPerRequest.ItemID AND RequestID = '$requestID'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row ['Quantity'] . " ";
        echo $row['ItemDescription'];
            if ($row['Quantity'] > 1) {
            echo "s";
            }
        echo " <br> ";
        }
echo "Comments: " . $row1['Comments'];
echo "<br> File Name: " . $row1['FileLink'];
$file = $row1['FileLink'];

}
```

Which works beautifully, and gives me this output for example 
Name: Sharkn8do 
Date Needed: 2016-12-28 
Company: Beverage 
Account: Buffalo Bar
Brand: Grand 
Wants: 4 Flyer - Large 11"x17"s 
18 Table Tent - A Frame Styles 
Comments: Now on draft Grand Canyon coffee bean stout
File Name: 2016-12-08-000000015-Me.jpg

Now, I want that output in an email body. I tried copying and pasting it into the

```
$message = "Form submission";
```

part of my mail() code.. but that really didn't work. all I want is the echo part in the code. BUT! because the Wants: (4 flyer, 18 table tent) part is generated based on an array, I can't really assign variables and send the subject as that, right?

Here is the mail code:

```
$to = "test@email.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$message = //WHAT DO;

$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
```

NO PHPMailer or similar recommendations. I tried it, don't like it, doesn't work... so mail() only would be preferred please.

Comment: show us the mail code

Comment: Instead of echo'ing, create a variable named something like `$output='';` and replace each echo with `$output .= [text to be echo'ed here];`. That will create a string with what would have been echo'ed out. Then you can echo out the value at the end for display or add it to an email.

Comment: "NO PHPMailer or similar recommendations."  really if your want advise you should be open to all options and phpmailer is 100 times better than php's built in mail(). but that's not an issue here, just an observation.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn okay, but I am echoing $row['ItemDescription']; which can be multiple items, and is in this example.the item flyer and the table tent were both echoed this way. if i say $var = $row['ItemDescription']; won't that var just change each time the while loop runs?

Comment: note the `.= ` the dot means add to the existing variable

Comment: @Dagon I can't get PHPMailer to work... at all... rather than do 5 hours of error checking, i'd rather do 1 hour of coding.

Comment: not `=`, use `.=`. That will keep appending text to the previous value instead of overwriting it. That is shorthand for saying `$var = $var . "some text";`.

Comment: if you send a lot of email (and or you dont want it to all end up marked as spam), it would be worth it, your call.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn why dont you add a quick 'answer' (easy points ;-))

Comment: @Dagon This email will be going to the same email address every time, and the email will be the same format everytime, no more than 20 emails a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echo'ing, create a variable named something like `$output='';` and replace each echo with `$output .= [text to be echo'ed here];`. That will create a string with what would have been echo'ed out. Then you can echo out the value at the end for display or add it to an email.

For example:

```
$output = "";

//just a simple loop
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    //basically what you have echo'ing a string in a loop.
    //echo "The loop is on number: {$i}\n";

    //what you should do with concatenation
    $output .= "The loop is on number: {$i}\n";
}

//now you have a variable with the same text that
//would have been echo'ed. You can echo it here to
//get the same output or use it somewhere else.
echo $output;

//or email it
mail($to, $subject, "This is the output: {$output}", $headers);
```